# Python OpenCV video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC) always returns 0.0

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I am using python and OpenCV to read video from RTSP. The minimal code is like:

```py
import cv2

url = 'rtsp://user:password@192.168.1.64'

video = cv2.VideoCapture(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    key = 0
    while key != 27:
        ret, frame = video.read()

        cv2.imshow('img', frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
```

And under some specific situation, my video is not fluent. It freezes a little moment periodically. **Let's say every 1 seconds it freezes 100ms.**

After some search, I consider it is because the code format is not properly seted. So I tried to using get the fourcc code of the video stream.

```py
import cv2

video = cv2.VideoCapture(url)

fourcc = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC)
```

But the fourcc is always 0.0. I tried ways below but no use.

```py
import cv2

video = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc(*"MJPG"))

fourcc = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC)
```

But the output is still 0.0.

**My questions are:**

- **When reading rtsp, my video freezes periodically. What may be the cause?**
- **If it is the fourcc things, how can I set it right?**

Comment: What do you mean the video sticks? When you write to a video, it will just repeat a bunch of frames in a row? Can you give a [mcve] of your video writing issue specifically?

Comment: @alkasm I have edited my question. The "sticks" here means "freezes". The freezing problem is about reading video from rtsp and show it with `cv2.imshow`, nothing about writing a video file.

Comment: Ah I see. I sort of doubt it's a fourcc issue, then. If it's working periodically, it seems more of an issue to do with your network connection. OpenCV's video functionality is a lot of different things patched to work together, mostly for convenience---it's not all very great for actual production use-cases. I would suggest to look into other libraries, personally.

Comment: Thank you ^_^. Any suggestions? I am now considering using ffmpeg.

Comment: ffmpeg is probably the most well supported. It should be relatively easy to translate the data to an OpenCV Mat (or numpy array) once you are able to ingest the stream data from the URL.